# Weird gap between columns with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have a weird gap between my columns, which should be removed. But when I set the column-gap to 0px, there remains a 1px gap.

You can see it here:

http://onezeromany.com/results.html

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. If your site goes down, your question is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove width and don't set the no repeat, I removed the width and disabled background-repeat. After I have don this, the border was gone.

the class looks no like this

```
.tile {
height: 310px;
background-position: center top;
}
```

Hope this is it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the width on .tile has something to do with it